# Increasing a number in a listview via button

Tags: android, listview

I'm developing in Android Studio.
I have a ListView that every item in it contains number of elements including 2 Buttons:increase/decrease and a EditText filed:edit_txt .
I need that in each click on the button "increase" will increase the number in the edit_txt filed.
As well as in every click on the button "decrease" it will decrease the number in the edit_txt filed.
how do i make it work?

The class called "ProductList" and it expands AppCompatActivity.

```js
package com.example.yuliaaa.myapplication;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ProductList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<myProductsView> myProducts_types = new ArrayList<myProductsView>();
    ArrayAdapter<myProductsView> adapter;

    private ArrayList<myProductsView>  choosen_items = new ArrayList<myProductsView>();
    ListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pop_productlist);

        populateProductsList();
        populateListView();

    }

    private void populateProductsList() {
        myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("p1", "d1", 1111, 12.90, R.drawable.cereal, 1));
        myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("p2", "dddd", 1112, 10.90, R.drawable.cereal, 2));
        myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("p3", "ffff", 1112, 30.00, R.drawable.cereal, 1));
        myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("p4", "kkkkk", 1112, 20.00, R.drawable.cereal, 3));

    }

    private void populateListView() {
        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.product_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
    public void StartCalck(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProductList.this, SplitBuying.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void deleteItems(View view){


        for(int i=0;i<choosen_items.size();i++){
            adapter.remove(choosen_items.get(i));
        }

    }






    public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myProductsView>{



        public MyListAdapter(){
            super(ProductList.this, R.layout.pop_productlist, myProducts_types);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //make sure we have a view to work with(may have been given null

            View itemView = convertView;

            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product_item_view, parent, false);
            }
            //we need to populate the list
            //find the product to work with
            final myProductsView currentProduct = myProducts_types.get(position);



       //fill the view
            final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_checkBox);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    choosen_items.add(currentProduct);
                }
            });



            TextView productname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            productname.setText(currentProduct.getProductName());

            EditText quantity = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
            quantity.setText(String.valueOf(currentProduct.getQuantity()));

            Button increase = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);


            increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            return itemView;
        }

    }


    

}
```

The class **myProductsView** is class that represent a product.
The **productlist.xml** contains the ListView with the id: mylist.
And the product_item_view.xml which is how every item in the list view would look like contains:
-Checkbox:"product_checkBox"
-TextView:"product_name"
-Button:"btn_plus"
-EditText:"edit_text"
-Button:"btn_minus"

thank you,

Comment: i suppose on each click on button add or subtract you have to a text view by inflating the layout and notifydatasetchanged(); after clicking

Comment: Sorry i don't really understand what you mean, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                  myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("p5", "abc", 100, 100.00, R.drawable.wheat, 4));
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: i need to increase the quantity in the EditText filed , i tried doing  quantity.setText(String.valueOf(currentProduct.getQuantity()+1)); inside onClick , it increases the edit_txt filed by 1 but if i click more than once it won't do anything

Comment: Change specifc product quantity and simply call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: i need it to work for 1 button click or more ,means that if the user clicks on the increasing button number of times the edit_txt filed should get increased as many times as he clicked

Comment: i noticed that when i try doing quantity.setText(String.valueOf(currentProduct.getQuantity()+1)); inside onClick the EditText quantity = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text); changes to final which make it non changeable, how do i overcome it?

Comment: Add EditText quantity ; before onCreate of Activity.i think there should be happened with final EditText quantity

Comment: i worte: final EditText quantity = (EditText)View.findViewById(R.id.edit_text); before the onCreate but i have a problem with "findViewById" it says "Non static method 'findViewById(int)' cannot be referenced from static context"